# PHP Imap get message body

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I am connection to a mailbox and getting header information for each message like this:

```
$mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox(
    env('MAIL_IMAP_PATH') . env('MAIL_FOLDER'), // IMAP server and mailbox folder
    env('MAIL_LOGIN'), // Username for the before configured mailbox
    env('MAIL_PASSWORD') // Password for the before configured username
);
$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');
foreach($mailsIds as $mail_elem) {
    $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mail_elem);
}
```

`getMail` gives me all the header info without the body. I have checked now every single method which exists on `$mailbox->` and there is no way to get the body. What am I doing wrong here?

---

Second approach is to use the stream from `imap_open()` and `imap_fetchbody()`. This feels more like a workaround because I connect a second time to the mailbox, but is also does not work:

```
foreach($mailsIds as $mail_elem) {
    $imap_stream = imap_open(env('MAIL_IMAP_PATH') . env('MAIL_FOLDER'),
                        env('MAIL_LOGIN'), env('MAIL_PASSWORD'));
    $message = imap_fetchbody($imap_stream, $mail_elem, 1.1);
}
```

I am getting an error:

> imap_fetchbody(): Bad message number

Does someone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: What is the value of `$mail_elem` (in the second approach I mean)?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, or even relevant to the error you're getting, but the section number for `imap_fetchbody()` should be a string, not a float: `, "1.1"`, as you can see [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php).

Comment: $mail_elem is the ID of the message, in my case it is 113. I tried now to cast it to string and I also tried to use "1.1" for the section, but the error remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the body with the `$mail` object not the `$mailbox` object.

```
foreach($mailsIds as $mail_elem) {
    $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mail_elem);
    $message = $mail->textHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the cause but the third parameter of fetchbody is a string, not a float, so write it like:

```
imap_fetchbody($imap_stream, $mail_elem, '1.1')
```

Your issue is probably about *$mail_elem* that's probably doesn't match with the index of the imap. In case they are UID, you need to add the flag **FT_UID** in the 4th paramates of *imap_fetchbody*.

Anyaway if you are planning to use imap_* library, I advise you to use this wrapper: [php-taniguchi](https://github.com/BlorisL/php-taniguchi/) (it's quite documented and it has an example [file](https://github.com/BlorisL/php-taniguchi/blob/main/example.php)).

The **read()** method is quite simple:
*read(int $from, int $number, bool $details = false, bool $seen = false, bool $attachments = false)*

Set all to true and you will get everything you want, it's quite easy:

```
$tmp = new \Taniguchi\Imap($account, $password, $url, $port);
$tmp->setSsl()->setValidate(false);
var_dump($tmp->read(1, 2, true, true, true));
```